# MVC2 routing issue: base url + action controler not working

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, url-routing

I'm sure I have missed something obvious on this because I'm still a bit of a novice with the MVC2 routing.

I have a website where xyz.com takes you to a request status page(a list of pages)  Upon clicking the request, I want to go to xyz.com/RequestDetails/{request id}

My current attempt at a maproute to get this to work is:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            "RequestDetails",
            "RequestDetails/(request)",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "RequestDetails", request = 0}
            );
```

Intuitively, the above should work but I am getting a 404 error when I attempt a call to xyz.com/RequestDetails/1234

I know the Home controller has an action named RequestDetails:

```
    public ActionResult RequestDetails(int request)
    {
    //my actions for this request
    }
```

I'm not sure what I've done wrong in the above but I'm sure I've got something very off :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        "RequestDetails",
        "RequestDetails/{request}",
        new { controller = "Home", action = "RequestDetails", request = 0}
        );
```

Note the change from parentheses to curly brackets.

Comment: Thank you Keith... even though it is afternoon, I need more coffee.  I'll accept this once the min time is up.